# nutch I am reading the content folder from segments.There is difference in stats report

Tags: nutch

I have given input urls to nutch to crawl the websites that is 1081220 urls.I had run one round of crawling.then i read the data from content folder that from segments directory.Read the data using spark and write data into json stored in s3.Then the read the json file that is stored in s3 when i read the no of urls are 796737 which i found content folder.
When i see fetcher status from yarn ui the value are

Name               Map                     Reduce                        Total
access_denied      327                        0                          327
bytes_downloaded  55,505,674,572              0                      55,505,674,572
exception           85,774                    0                         85,774
gone                 803                      0                          803
hitByThrougputThreshold 119,988               0                        119,988
moved                   129,703               0                        129,703
notfound                 25,511               0                         25,511
robots_denied             35,750              0                          35,750
robots_denied_maxcrawldelay 2,574             0                           2,574
success                     641,302           0                          641,302
temp_moved                   25,732           0                           25,732

---

crawldb stats are
status 1 (db_unfetched):15313970
status 2 (db_fetched):619429
status 3 (db_gone): 64965
status 4 (db_redir_temp):25732
status 5 (db_redir_perm):129703
status 7 (db_duplicate):21873

---

May I know why the differnences.which stats should i follow there is difference in all stats report that is content folder stats,fetcher status stats,crawldb stats.I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There can be differences between the Fetcher counters and the resulting CrawlDb status counts for a couple of reasons:

1. of course, the CrawlDb holds items from all cycles and even the URLs injected or found as outlinks but not yet tried to fetched
2. some Fetcher counters have no 1:1 correspondence to a DB status: eg., "gone", "notfound" and "robots_denied" all result in "db_gone"
3. other DB statuses are set by other Nutch components, eg. "db_duplicate" by the dedup job
4. in case Fetcher follows redirects: Fetcher does by default not deduplicate redirects, so if multiple redirects point to the same URL, it is fetched multiple times. This leads to a higher value in the Fetcher counter "success" compared to the resulting count of items with status "db_fetched".

Comment: I have set http.redirect.max=0 and what about the content folder value i have read the content folder value using spark taking columns the url,content type,content.May I know why there is difference of stats between the content stats and crawldb stats.

Comment: when i read the no of urls in content folder 796737 why there is difference in crawldb

Comment: The major difference results from the fact that the CrawlDb includes all outlinks found in the fetched pages (15 million items). The content subdir in the segment includes successfully fetched pages, but also redirects and 404s as these also have content (a HTML page with a message about the redirection or the error).

Comment: How could i filter the records while reading the data from spark.I want only the records which are fetched.

Comment: (a) join the Content objects in the "content subdir with the CrawlDatum objects in "crawl_fetch". The latter will include the fetch status.

(b) if it's only about the plain text: the folder "parse_text" holds the extracted text only of successful fetches

(c) alternatively: add the fetch status to the content metadata, e.g. set store.http.headers == true and look into the status line of the HTTP response header

Comment: b)I am not interested in the parse_text.

Comment: when I read the crawl_fetch output is Array[(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDatum)] =
Array((http://agents.allstate.com,Version: 7
Status: 36 (fetch_redir_perm)
Fetch time: Mon Oct 12 19:09:54 IST 2020
Modified time: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
Score: 1.0
Signature: null
Metadata:
  _ngt_=1602509908612
 _pst_=moved(12), lastModified=0: https://agents.allstate.com
 _rs_=39
 Content-Type=application/octet-stream
 nutch.protocol.code=301
********************************************

Comment: the ouput is similar to the crawldb output .I have one doubt that crawldb is reading the data from crawl_fetch

Comment: after crawling process  so we can delete the crawldb as well because we got the output.

Comment: The "update" job reads the CrawlDatum items from "crawl_fetch" and "crawl_parse" and updates the CrawlDb by changing the fetch status resp. by adding newly found links as unfetched items. If you delete the CrawlDb you cannot continue with more crawl cycles.

Comment: here the read the craw_fetch so i can join content directory data and crawl_fetch on basis of url.So there is no need of the parse_text.

Comment: so that i only filter records based on fetch status.

Comment: store.http.headers == true may i know what it means.So here it will create new column for content directory with fetch status.